# Why is LinkedHashSet Iteration faster than HashSet iteration in Java?

Tags: java, hashset, linkedhashset

Here is a sample code:

```
    Set<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> linkedHashSet = new HashSet<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        hashSet.add(i);
        linkedHashSet.add(i);
    }

    Long startTimeHashSet = System.nanoTime();
    for(Integer i: hashSet){

    }
    Long endTimeHashSet = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("HashSet Time:" + (endTimeHashSet - startTimeHashSet));

    Long startTimeLinkedHashSet = System.nanoTime();
    for(Integer i: linkedHashSet){

    }
    Long endTimeLinkedHashSet = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Linked HashSet Time:" + (endTimeLinkedHashSet - startTimeLinkedHashSet));
```

The output is:

```
HashSet Time:721774
Linked HashSet Time:132613
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Your benchmark suffers from 2 of the standard problems of naive Java benchmarking.  1) It does not account for JVM warmup.  2) The loops *could be* optimized away.

Comment: I tweaked your code to address the warmup problem, and the true performance difference is minimal.